# C# WinForms SplitContainer Panel Toolbar

Tags: winforms, toolbar, .net-6.0

WinForms .NET 6.03 (C#)

In a Form that has a traditional menu and toolbar docked across the top...

I have a split container (vertical splitter) in the left panel I have a toolbar docked to the top and a user control filling Panel1 below the panel's toolbar.

When I resize the panel, the toolbar disappears and the user control shifts up in the panel.

This was not a problem in .NET 4.6.  I'm only seeing it now that I'm building in .NET 6.03

Is there a fix?

[image]

Comment: Try calling `this.Invalidate();` at the end of the `Resize` event handler.

Comment: No luck. Unless I'm not understanding. I added a handler the the panel's resize event.... 

`private void splitContainerUpper_Panel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 '{ 
        splitContainerUpper.Panel1.Invalidate(); // tried no luck 
        splitContainerUpper.Invalidate(); // tried no luck 
        this.Invalidate(); // 
        invalidate entire form - tried no luck 
    }`

Comment: What's the type of these white `ToolStrip` items? As you can see, no problem with the `ToolStrip` itself, no problem with the `ToolStripButton`, `ToolStripSeparator`, and the `ToolStripComboBox`.

Comment: It's  a   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip   ...containing several ToolStripButton items, a few ToolStripSeparator items and a ToolStripComboBox item

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that this was a z-order problem. Somehow during execution, the toolstrip was losing it's topmost condition regarding docking.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Don't forget to right-click on the **Project** and select **Sync Namespace** to update the namespace according to your project.

```
namespace DiscountCard.View.CustomControl
{
    public partial class CtechSplitContainer : SplitContainer
    {
        private ToolStripContainer toolStripContainer1;
        private ToolStrip toolStrip1;
        private ToolStripButton button1;

        private ToolStripContainer toolStripContainer2;
        private ToolStrip toolStrip2;
        private ToolStripButton button2;

        public CtechSplitContainer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            toolStripContainer1 = new ToolStripContainer();
            toolStrip1 = new ToolStrip();
            button1 = new ToolStripButton();

            button1.Text = "";
            button1.Click += Button1_Click;
            button1.DoubleClick += Button1_DoubleClick;

            // Add items to the ToolStrip.
            ToolStripItem[] toolStripItem1 = new ToolStripItem[] { button1 };
            toolStrip1.Items.AddRange(toolStripItem1);
            toolStrip1.LayoutStyle = ToolStripLayoutStyle.Table;
            toolStrip1.BackColor = Color.White;
            toolStrip1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

            // Add the ToolStrip to the top panel of the ToolStripContainer.
            toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.Controls.Add(toolStrip1);
            toolStripContainer1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
            toolStripContainer1.Height = button1.Width;
            toolStripContainer1.Width = button1.Width;

            // Add the ToolStripContainer to the Panel1.
            this.Panel1.Controls.Add(toolStripContainer1);
            this.Panel1.BackColor = Color.White;


            toolStripContainer2 = new ToolStripContainer();
            toolStrip2 = new ToolStrip();
            button2 = new ToolStripButton();

            button2.Text = "";
            button2.Click += Button2_Click;
            button2.DoubleClick += Button2_DoubleClick;

            // Add items to the ToolStrip.
            ToolStripItem[] toolStripItem2 = new ToolStripItem[] { button2 };
            toolStrip2.Items.AddRange(toolStripItem2);
            toolStrip2.LayoutStyle = ToolStripLayoutStyle.Table;
            toolStrip2.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

            // Add the ToolStrip to the top panel of the ToolStripContainer.
            toolStripContainer2.TopToolStripPanel.Controls.Add(toolStrip2);
            toolStripContainer2.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
            toolStripContainer2.Height = button2.Width;
            toolStripContainer2.Width = button2.Width;
            toolStrip2.BackColor = Color.White;

            // Add the ToolStripContainer to the Panel2.
            this.Panel2.Controls.Add(toolStripContainer2);
            this.Panel2.BackColor = Color.White;

            this.SplitterWidth = 1;

            if (this.Orientation == Orientation.Vertical)
            {
                this.SplitterDistance = this.ClientSize.Width / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                this.SplitterDistance = this.ClientSize.Height / 2;
            }

            this.BackColor = Color.White;
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (button1.Text == "")
            {
                button1.Text = "";
                this.Panel1Collapsed = false;
                this.Panel2Collapsed = true;
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Text = "";
                this.Panel1Collapsed = false;
                this.Panel2Collapsed = false;
            }
        }
        private void Button1_DoubleClick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
        }

        private void Button2_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (button2.Text == "")
            {
                button2.Text = "";
                this.Panel1Collapsed = true;
                this.Panel2Collapsed = false;
            }
            else
            {
                button2.Text = "";
                this.Panel1Collapsed = false;
                this.Panel2Collapsed = false;
            }
        }
        private void Button2_DoubleClick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button2.PerformClick();
        }

    }
}
```

Result

**1. Normal**

[image]

**2. Maximized**

[image]